# How do I line number a set of columns taking into account the strings values of the first column (UNIX shell)

Tags: bash, for-loop, unix, awk

Can someone help me? I would like to number a tabulated file in UNIX depends on the columns in that file. However, the last column from some rows have SAME LETTERS AND LENGTH between them but different order and must be considered the same if the other previous columns are the same too. In summary, the input is something like

```
rs758613821  574290     insertion_inframe   P   285  AAAP
rs758613821  574290     insertion_inframe   P   285  APAA
rs758613821  574290     insertion_inframe   P   285  APLA
rs1367252071 574290     deletion_inframe    CADDL   134  F
rs538        3246       frameshift_variant  F   97  FGLYP
rs538        3246       frameshift_variant  F   97  PYFLG
```

And the output should be

```
1 rs758613821    574290     insertion_inframe   P   285  AAAP
1 rs758613821    574290     insertion_inframe   P   285  APAA
2 rs758613821    574290     insertion_inframe   P   285  APLA
3 rs1367252071   574290     deletion_inframe    CADDL   134  F
4 rs538          3246       frameshift_variant  F   97  FGLYP
4 rs538          3246       frameshift_variant  F   97  PYFLG
```

and so on...

In this way I have performed the code as follow

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} function intern(sym) { if (sym in table)
                          return table[sym]
                        return table[sym] = ++counter }
 { print intern($1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6), $0 }' "input" > "output";
```

Nevertheless I didn't solve the problem concerning to the last column to assign the same number if are same letters and length although different order. Is it possible to do it in UNIX environment? I think maybe by means of substr function or similar like that but I'm not sure what will be a properly code. Thanks in advance for the support and helping!

Comment: Thanks so much for correct and reedit the title @gregory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want to do but give it a try

```
$ awk 'function canon(f) {n=split(f,a,""); 
                          asort(a); c=""; 
                          for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c=c a[i]; 
                          return c;}
                         {key=canon($NF)} 
          !(key in keys) {keys[key]=++ctr} 
                         {print keys[key],$0}' file

1 rs758613821  574290     insertion_inframe   P   285  AAAP
1 rs758613821  574290     insertion_inframe   P   285  APAA
2 rs758613821  574290     insertion_inframe   P   285  APLA
3 rs1367252071 574290     deletion_inframe    CADDL   134  F
4 rs538        3246       frameshift_variant  F   97  FGLYP
4 rs538        3246       frameshift_variant  F   97  PYFLG
```

convert the last field into canonical form and count the unique instances.

To use the full record as key do this instead

```
                 ...
                 {line=$0;
                  $NF=canon($NF);
                  key=$0} 
  !(key in keys) {keys[key]=++ctr} 
                 {print keys[key],line}' file
```

copy the line, replace last field with canonical form, use the updated line as key, count unique instances, print count and original line

Comment: Works correctly! thanks so much @karafka, however I need to take account the other columns too. In this way, if 3rd column for 2nd row for instance its different respect to the previous row the number must be different too and will become number 2 instead of number 1

Comment: Are there any possibility to include within the code to take account it? Nevertheless thanks again for helping!

Comment: Ok, I have solved it. Enough of replace key=canon($NF) to key=canon($0) to take account the other columns. I understood the majority part of the code but there are some parts that are confused for me. Is it possible to explain me superficially?

Comment: Don't do that, it may give you false matches.  See the updated version instead.  Let me know what part is not clear.

Comment: If I understand correctly (for your updating) first of all defines a "canon" function doing split of "f" and convert it to the canonical form( asort ) and then apply the canon function in the last field to become in a canonical form. Then key=$0 to take account entire line and if there is a new entire line then counter. Finally print number and $0. Thanks so much again anyway for helping @karafka

Comment: yes, correct.  Since the order is not important for the last field chars, the easiest is to sort and compare them.